# list of Bytes object to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of Bytes (strings) which is separated by "\n".
I want to create a data frame from the list, and to separate each element to 15 columns.
I have succeeded to separate the rows but I'm getting 1 column instead of 15.

```
from io import BytesIO
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(b'\n'.join(tmp)), sep = '\n')
df
```

my output looks like this:
[image]

row example: 
b"US\t20422322\tR8MEA6IGAHO0B\tB00MC4CED8\t217304173\tBlackVue DR600GW-PMP\tMobile_Electronics\t5\t0\t0\tN\tY\tVery Happy!\tAs advertised. Everything works perfectly, I'm very happy with the camera. As a matter of fact I'm going to buy another one for my 2nd car.\t2015-08-31\n"
b'\n'

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduceable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your output it looks like your `tmp` list contains `\t` characters already, which would imply that the `\t` character is the separator in the data and not `\n` as you have specified. It is unlikely that `\n` is a separator between columns, which is what the `sep` argument of `read_csv()` refers to, so I think you may be getting confused with the `\n` you're using as a separator between rows.

Try instead to do the following:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(b'\n'.join(tmp)), sep='\t')
```